# How to auto scale of Java War Deployment Setup

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rest, jackson, war

I have a **Java Tomcat War** Deployment Setup on **AWS EC2** Ubuntu Linux Machine. And this server is based on some APIs and some computation. Now, it is consuming 15% to 20% Server CPU Utilization. And sometimes, it goes upto the 80%(rare case). How can I do auto-scaling the for multiple setup on the different AZs dynamically?

I have **Asia Mumbai Region** which has three Availability Zones and I have deployed only in one zone. If the load goes up, I add the instance on the different AZs manually. But I don't know how to do this dynamically without *manually setup* as AWS autoscaling group does for the stateless things.

Every comment will be welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some way for an instance to be fully operational without intervention. This tends to be the complicated part, and there's no one "answer" to it. It usually means one of two things:

- A cloud-init script that sets up the instance when it starts up (either directly with bash scripts or using a config management tool like Chef, Puppet, etc)
- A "golden image", i.e. an AMI that is already fully set up and can start serving as soon as it boots up

Once you've got that, you create a Launch Config that defines what an instance should look like - instance type, disk(s), AMI, user data (where a cloud-init script would go), machine role, security groups, etc.

Then you create an Auto-Scale Group and attach the LC to it. The auto-scale group will create your instances instead of you creating them. If you want, you can attach your hand-rolled instance to the ASG. The ASG lets you specify what subnets to create instances in; give it at least one subnet for each AZ where you want instances created. It will automatically spread created instances across AZs. The ASG has min, max, and desired instance counts. Desired count is how many instances it should have at any given time; if there are less than this, it will create more, if there are more than this, it will terminate some according to the termination policy (oldest first, newest first, etc.) Min and max define boundaries on desired count - desired will never be less than min or more than max.

Last, you define scale-out and scale-in rules to say when it should automatically change the desired count. In your case this might be to scale out when average CPU use across the ASG is over 50% and scale in when it's under 25%.

You'll also want to set the ASG as the target group for your load balancer, so that as soon as a new instance is created and goes healthy, it will take traffic - otherwise, what was the point of creating it? Make sure you have an accurate health check so that instances that cannot serve traffic don't receive traffic.